# Anchor URL with ID not correct because fixed header

Tags: html, css

I use a fixed header on our website with a height of 58px.

Now I want to link to a anchor on the page, but that does not work, because the startpoint of the anchor is behind the header.

I cannot give the specific anchor section a margin or padding to top, because that is displayed to ugly.

I use something like:

```
<a href="#test">Test link</a>
```

And:

```
<p id="test" class="anchor">
```

How can I change the startpoint of the anchor, so that it starts after the header.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vrLs0wkk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy. Add a new element within your target `p` element and give that the `id` attribute instead:

```
<p>
    <span id="test" class="anchor-point"></span>
    ...
</p>
```

Now set your `p` element to have relative positioning:

```css
p {
    position: relative;
}
```

Then set your new `.anchor-point` element to be positioned somewhere above the top of your `p` element and give it `visibility: hidden` to make it completely invisible:

```css
.anchor-point {
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vrLs0wkk/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css.

```
:target:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    margin: -180px 0 0;
}
```

Change height to what you prefer.